# How can I access `event_value_in_usd` for an `in_app_purchase` event in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, in-app-purchase, google-analytics-firebase

When I export Firebase events to BigQuery, I see a column called `event_value_in_usd` for the `in_app_purchase` event. Does this mean that I could access this value somehow in the app using the SDK, or is the USD conversion value only available in BigQuery? The motivation behind the question is to log the $USD value of purchases to a custom event.